# How to host a website on Heroku without using heroku's own http router?

Tags: heroku

I need to host a website on Heroku, but I need to have direct access to the HTTP traffic without Heroku's own http router meddling in.

Comment: [You cannot](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing). If you really need that, find another host. But [maybe you don't really need what you think you do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627): what kind of "meddling" are you concerned about?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible.
Heroku doesn't provide a full server infrastruture.
It's rather a limited platform to host HTTP services.